# What is the exact opposite of teach?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

So, if teaching is the insertion of knowledge from one person to another, then the opposite of that is the extraction of that knowledge.

So for e.g, if I was to read up on the history of the slave trade, then to 'unteach me', you'd have to employ some sort of technique to eliminate that specific piece of information. You can think of it in the same as deleting data from a computer, to draw upon an analogy (well... I guess some would see little distinction)

Comment: Many would say the opposite of *teach* is *learn*; others, *unlearn*.  It really depends what you mean by “opposite”.

Comment: I wonder if you're speaking of [brainwashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_control).

Comment: I  mean in the sense of the removal of information vs the implementation of it, which is basically what teaching is.

Comment: Short of destroying part of the brain, there would seem no way to effect this. I'm not sure that such a word would make sense.

Comment: The *opposite* is, er, teach - Teach me how to XXX.  Teach me how *not* to XXX.

Comment: I think you have to say "teach someone to forget" or "teach someone to unlearn" or "make someone forget".

Comment: Sci-Fi books often talk of "wiping people's memory" ...

Comment: Most words don't have exact opposites.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of receiving downvotes (a risk I am willing to take), the exact opposite of *teach* is **unteach**. How one goes about **unteaching** is a different matter altogether, outside the scope of the question, which is "What is the exact opposite of teach?"

Answer (score 0):

*Repattern*

I'm afraid I can't find a definition.  [Wordnik has examples](https://www.wordnik.com/words/repattern), such as

> Through implementing certain rigorous and intense physical rehabilitation practices, for example, stroke victims and those with traumatic brain injuries have been able to successfully repattern the neurons in their brains.

Here's a badly written sentence taken from http://www.selfgrowth.com/articles/neuro-hypnotic-repatterning-what-is-it-and-what-can-it-do-for-you
that nevertheless gives a feel for the word:

> These are all learned behaviours, and when you hypnotically repattern someone what you are basically doing is teaching them not to get to what they don’t want to get.

This seems to be me to be related to *desensitization*, which is part of the treatment for obsessive-compulsive disorder (exposure and response prevention).

Answer (score 0):

***Memory erasure*** — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_erasure)

> It is the selective artificial removal of memories or associations from the mind.
>
> There are many reasons that research is being done on the selective removal of memories. Potential patients for this research include patients suffering from psychiatric disorders such as post traumatic stress disorder, or substance use disorder, among others.

See also: ["Scientists have discovered how to 'delete' unwanted memories"](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/science/2016/03/12/scientists-have-discovered-how-to-delete-unwanted-memories/).

Like Jim [commented](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/349020/what-is-the-exact-opposite-of-teach#comment808210_349020), Sci-Fi books often use ***wipe (someone's) memory***, (or *erase*, *delete*, etc. + *memory*, *mind*, etc.)

***Wipe out*** — [TFD/Kernerman](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wipe+out)

> 2. to remove; to get rid of.
>    *"You must try to wipe out the memory of these terrible events."*

See [examples from Google Books](https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=bks&q=wipe%20out%20his%20her%20memory).